# Can't get PHP PDO and OOP classes to work

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, pdo

I am trying to learn how to use PHP PDO as Object Oriented Programming.

I have tried following these two tutorials:
http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/
http://culttt.com/2012/09/24/prevent-php-sql-injection-with-pdo-prepared-statements/

but I can't get anything on either of them to work.

The second one gives a download link to a pre-written wrapper class `class.db.php` from http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/

using this pre-written wrapper class and trying something as simple as this `tutorial.php` (credentials changed):

```
// Include the database class
include("class.db.php");

// Connect to database
$db = new db("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my-db-name", "my-username", "my-password");

$results = $db->select("ad_publication");
print_r($results);
```

The above shows a blank page.

I know there is nothing wrong with the pre-written class and the text of the above example as it was copied directly out of the tutorial and the comments are full of thanks and praise.

I know there is nothign wrong with my credentials as this works fine:

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my-db-name', 'my-username', 'my-password');

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');

    $output = 'Connection Successful';
    echo $output;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.' . $e->getMessage();
    echo $output;
    exit();
    }
```

And outputs `Connection Successful`

My Server is running PHP 5.5 and the table used in the example above is an `InnoDB` table.

When I run the example select statement my error logs show:

> **PHP Notice:** Undefined variable: GhG678 in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com.au/httpdocs/booking/tutorial.php on line 7

**line 7:**

```
$db = new db("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my-db-name", "my-username", "my-password");
```

> **PHP Warning:** Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com.au/httpdocs/booking/class.db.php on line 18

**line 18:**

```
$this->error = $e->getMessage(); // (from public function __construct)`
```

> **PHP Fatal error:** Call to a member function select() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com.au/httpdocs/booking/tutorial.php on line 9

**line 9:**

```
$results = $db->select("ad_publication"); // (an existing table with data in it)
```

I just can't see what I could be doing wrong especially as the wrapper class was not written by me and no-one else is complaining about it (heaps of praise) and the contents of tutorial.php were copied directly from the page with only the table name changed.

Like I say, using the PDO connection and doing normal PDO queries without the wrapper class, work fine.

Can anyone here see anything that could be going wrong or know of anything that I should look at?

Comment: so you provide links to the tutorials, but not to your `class.db.php`? since the error is happening with your code, don't you think it would be helpful to show that?

Comment: I'd guess you've made a mistake in  your version of `tutorial.php` since that variable name that PHP says is undefined looks rather like a password. You should post _your_ code here rather than claiming that there's nothing wrong.

Comment: Does `"my-username"` or `"my-password"` look like `"$GhG678"`? where you forgot to remove the `$`, so it thinks `GhG678` is a var `$GhG678` instead of a string?

Comment: You say "The above shows a blank page." which indicates a fatal error. You should put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the page and that should tell you what is wrong there.

Comment: RE: **put on hold**. Knowing now that it was caused by a lack of understanding syntax, makes it hard to edit this question to be more on topic.  Especially since the problem was within a password, (not included) All code and error logs were included, except the file class.db.php written by someone else and publicly available (link provided) which was not the problem. I have read help center links and can't see how I could have made it more on topic.
I am glad I posted the question here, and that the generosity of people like @Sean helped me to find the solution and to learn more about this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why I copped a -1 for that question??
I thought it was very complete.

Anyway, thanks to @Sean for providing the clue to the answer.

My password does in fact have a $ character in it.

The connection code of mine that does work (as shown above) is:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my-db-name', 'my-username', 'my-password');
```

Their code that I was using is:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my-db-name", "my-username", "my-password");
```

changing the `"` characters to `'` worked straight away.
The password was auto-generated by my hosts (Plesk) and I don't know enough about PHP to know that there is a difference between `'` and `"`. I've never known why some people use one and some use the other. Seems I still have a lot to learn.

@Sean, because you didn't put it as a reply, I couldn't choose your suggestions as the answer, so I don't know how to give you the points, but thank you very much for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: you can learn more about how php deals with single quotes and double quotes at https://php.net/language.types.string. for example, `$x = 2; $y ='$x'; echo $y; // returns $x` but `$x = 2; $y ="$x"; echo $y; returns 2` as `The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.`

Comment: Thanks @Sean reading now.